# SMT soldering for QFN package without legs

Tags: soldering, surface-mount, qfn

I have soldered through-hole and SMT before but this is the first time I have to do SMT (QFN) package which has no legs. I tried the traditional approach, Flux, solder, then heating the component. But here the pads are underneath that it's been a nightmare to reach em to apply heat.

I worked with somebody back in the day who soldered in a different way. He applied something on the pads(very thick paste), I'm guessing Solder/flux paste. It managed to keep the components right where there are. Then he put the board in a microwave and ran it for a few minutes. Then the components were soldered perfectly. No issues what so ever.

My question is, what's that paste? Is my guess right? What exactly is it called so that I can buy one?

If I'm wrong, then how does one normally solder these components?

My component is a micro msp430fr2433.

Comment: Toaster oven, **NOT** microwave oven. And don't use it for food, ever, after this, especially if you use lead-based solder.

Comment: There are a bunch of similar questions on this site about soldering QFN (take a look at them for ideas), but the usual way is with reflow soldering.  You can also do it with an iron, although this is more difficult.

Comment: The thick substance must be solder paste.

Comment: Try tiny strip of  foil in a microwave (not)

Comment: I realize that. I'll not use it for food ever again.

Comment: A lot of components specify temperature profiles for reflow soldering. You could use that as a guideline regarding required oven temperature.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is solder paste (mixture of tiny balls of solder and flux) and a reflow oven.  The paste can be applied using a syringe or by speading the paste over the board using a stencil.

For small numbers, I'd just use a regular soldering iron, a fine tip, and a roll of thin solder and do them by hand.

---

I've never heard of using a microwave oven for reflow soldering.  High power microwaves would almost certainly damage the board or the components.

Hobbyists often modify toaster ovens for reflow use.

Maybe your coworker used a microwave oven with a "grill" function like a toaster oven where the microwave function isn't used.

Comment: You could be right. It's been years. So I don't exactly remember what it was. Do you think this will work? https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/chip-quik-inc/TS391AX50/7802229

I'll apply this to the pads, place the components, then place the board in a toaster oven for a few minutes.

Comment: I don't do reflow.  I'd just get out the soldering iron and have at it.

Comment: @varun that solder paste is OK. it has relatively low melting point, so should be easy to use with heat gun too

Comment: @maple Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly would not use a microwave oven here.  That runs the risk of damaging your board, components, and also the oven itself.

I've had good success with a "rework reflow" process where you do the following:

1. Apply suitable flux to the pads and to the pins on the device.
2. Apply a small bead of low temp solder paste to the pads.  It's OK if there is some between the pads.
3. Place the part using some glue under the center if it won't stay put.
4. Use a heat gun that produces a high enough temperature to flow your solder paste to the  pads until the solder reflows.

Alternatively you can use a hot plate or a toaster oven to heat the entire board but I've had the best luck with the heat gun.

Comment: They seem pretty pricey. I just need to solder this one component this way. I can solder other SMT packages without any issues. Unless there is no other option, I would not wanna buy a heat gun.

Comment: I got a small heat gun that is sold in craft stores.  Less than US$20.

Comment: But an oven will work, toaster oven, or a paint stripper heat gun from the hardware store.

Comment: There are many ways to do it.  You asked for how one does it.  I explained how I've done it with reasonable success.  The soldering iron "swipe" method also works but I've had a lot of trouble with solder bridging with that method.

Comment: Me too. Alright. I'll use a toaster oven. About the paste, is this the right one?  
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/chip-quik-inc/TS391AX50/7802229

I'll apply this to the pads, place the components, then place the board in a toaster oven for a few minutes.

Comment: I've used this: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/chip-quik-inc/SMD291AX10/2057271 and also this: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/chemtronics/CW8400/768491

Comment: Be VERY careful with a toaster oven.  It's easy for it to get WAY too hot.  That's why I like the hot air method.  You can see the solder flow and stop heating right away.

Comment: Thank all you for the suggestions. And yes, I will be careful.

Comment: Search for "Arduino smt oven control"

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use flux with solder paste, because solder paste already has flux in it. In fact, excess of flux can create extra problems when soldering QFN, just as excess of paste would.

Comment: When doing it this way I have found that using flux yields a better result.  But this is hardly a production ready process.  Your mileage may vary!

Comment: Alright. I'll just use solder paste. Put it in a toaster Oven. The moment I see solder flowing, I'll turn it off. Wait till It cools off then solder other components manually after. And this oven will only be used for this. Nothing else ever again.

Comment: It takes some practice.  Don't start with your good stuff!  Get some "SMT practice" boards and parts and get a feel for how this works.

Comment: @varun if you have other SMD components on a board you can do them all in one go. with added benefit that exposed pads/leads will give you better view of the melting process. It is hard to know when QFN is ready, unless your oven has thermal profile control

Comment: I'll put other SMT parts that have legs to keep an eye on the process. I don't want to put all the components. Some of the are through hole. Thanks for the advice.